# Dynamics CRM is it valid to import solution created in OnPrem to Online version of CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Lets say I have a on-prem and online version of Dynamics CRM. Is it possible to import the managed solution created in the onprem version to online version and also vice versa.

Is this valid and supported scenario or not? Any links or refernce around this?

Comment: It depends on what is in the solution. Most Entities, Optionsets etc should be fine; however if you have custom assemblies, there are differences between OnPrem and Cloud CRM (e.g. Sandbox limitations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking on the Microsoft documentation, the streams are kept separately for online and on-premises. So I doubt if it's supported across two. If you have the environments already, try and what's the message saying? :)

It would be good to have confirmation from Microsoft product/support team.
For solution import in the same stream, I use the following to check for solution version compatibility.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/maintain-managed-solutions?view=op-9-1

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info Jacqui, it is useful. Also Looks like it is supported to import solution developed in onprem to online but not sure about the version comaptiability.